# Retrieve mongodb document by order number in collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a mongodb collection which looks something like this;

```
[
  {
    "Code": "018906",
    "X": "0.12",
  },
  {
    "Code": "018907",
    "X": "0.18",
  },
  {
    "Code": "018910",
    "X": "0.24",
  },
  {
    "Code": "018916",
    "X": "0.75",
  },
]
```

Suppose I want to retrieve the 3rd document's `Code` field. I would like to use a python function something like this `retrieve_by_order(order_no=3, field='Code')` which will return `"018910"`. `order_no` points to the document position in the collection.

`Code` is arranged in ascending order.

I am open to using any python mongodb library. Solutions using pymongo, orm like mongoengine are welcome.

I am using python 3.7, mongodb v4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that the order of the data stored is the correct order, a lazy solution using pymongo would be something like:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(<creds>)
db = client.database
coll = db.coll

def retrieve_by_order(order_no, field="Code"):
    for i, post in enumerate(coll.find()):
         if i + 1 == order_no:
             return post[field]
```

A little faster solution would be to have the records hold an "order_no" field and you can directly query for it.

example:

```py
coll.find_one({"order_no": order_no})
```

You can set the order_no as incrementing index which can be set with the following code:

```py
result = db.collection.create_index([('order_no', pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Tested to work, although it is a bit slow. I guess your suggestion to use order_no as incrementing index is necessary for acceptable speed.